# Having to pass an empty object as parameter ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I create a class with default values like so -

```
class SomeClass {
    constructor({
        a = 0.00,
        b = 0.00,
        c = 14.00,
        d = 'xyz'
    }){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;

    }
}
```

I am having to pass an empty object while creating an instance.

```
var sc = new SomeClass({});
```

Is this normal if I want to set default values within a object parameter or can I change something in the constructor so that I can just do this `var sc = new SomeClass();` to create my object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the default value:

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor({
      a = 0.00,
      b = 0.00,
      c = 14.00,
      d = 'xyz'
  } = {}) { // <=
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
  }
}
```

Comment: @charsi That's weird, it seems the JavaScript code on codepen is not executed on the browser environment, it just works by using babel. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zt8h2feg/

Comment: Yep working in fiddle and js bin too. So an issue with codepen I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This syntax works in my Chrome:

```
class Test {
    constructor({a = 5} = {a: 6}) {
        console.log(a);
    }
}

new Test(); // 6
```

Comment: How do I do more than one parameter?

Comment: @charsi something like this i guess `constructor({a = 5, b = 6} = {a: 6, b: 7}, {c = 8} = {c: 9})`

Answer (score 1):

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor(optionsArg) {
    if (optionsArg === undefined) {
      optionsArg = {};
    }
    this.a = 'a' in optionsArg ? optionsArg.a : 0.00;
    this.b = 'b' in optionsArg ? optionsArg.b : 0.00;
    this.c = 'c' in optionsArg ? optionsArg.c : 14.00;
    this.d = 'd' in optionsArg ? optionsArg.d : 'xyz';
  }
}


var sc = new SomeClass({});
Object.keys(sc).forEach(function(prop){
console.log(prop, sc[prop]);
});
```

Comment: This works! thanks. I think you meant to leave the empty object out in the snippet.